# Scrapy: how to yield a list concatenated with append()

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm trying to yield or return a list with the append() function but I get some errors.

Is there a workaround to solve this? I commented some of the errors I've got.

Sorry, but I'm new into python coding.

```
class mySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "testspider"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.example.com/test-page.html',
    )

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('')), callback="parse_items", follow=True),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        item = myItem()

        #Extract some items
        item['status'] = response.status
        yield item

        inlinks = []
        links = LinkExtractor(canonicalize=False, unique=True).extract_links(response)
        for link in links:
            is_allowed = False
            for allowed_domain in self.allowed_domains:
                if allowed_domain in link.url:
                    is_allowed = True
            if is_allowed:
                inlink = anotherItem()
                inlink['url_from'] = response.url
                inlink['url_to'] = link.url
                inlinks.append(inlink)
        yield inlinks #ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'list' in <GET http://www.example.com/test-page.html>
        #if using yield inlink of course I get just the first element, in my case I get only the first URL for every unique page 
        #using return inlinks I get
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`yield` one item at a time. No need to create a list to return it at then end.

```
    for link in links:
        is_allowed = False
        for allowed_domain in self.allowed_domains:
            if allowed_domain in link.url:
                is_allowed = True
        if is_allowed:
            inlink = anotherItem()
            inlink['url_from'] = response.url
            inlink['url_to'] = link.url
            yield inlink
```

Answer (score -2):

Error message is clear that Spider must return `Request`, `BaseItem`, `dict` or `None`.

But you are returning a `list` (its called array in PHP)

```
    for link in links:
        is_allowed = False
        for allowed_domain in self.allowed_domains:
            if allowed_domain in link.url:
                is_allowed = True
        if is_allowed:
            inlink = anotherItem()
            inlink['url_from'] = response.url
            inlink['url_to'] = link.url
            yield inlink
```

You can use this code to prevent any errors, just yield 1 item at one time.

OR even if you want to return/yield all items at once, do this

```
    for link in links:
        is_allowed = False
        for allowed_domain in self.allowed_domains:
            if allowed_domain in link.url:
                is_allowed = True
        if is_allowed:
            inlink = anotherItem()
            inlink['url_from'] = response.url
            inlink['url_to'] = link.url
            inlinks.append(inlink)
    yield {'all_links': inlinks}
```